# how to convert date column of a file into user input format

Tags: linux, date, awk

I have a file it has 7 columns and lacks of raws its date column format and number of date columns are dynamic, maybe one or two or three columns, date formats are `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI` or `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI` or `DD/MON/YYYY HH:MI` etc..

file.txt

```
OIEX19|BANG37748|DEL37728|WUBXDE|200010291010|201209111625|195210290000
SEETA7|CHA38228|DEL37728|DGSDFE|201211190705|201308071912|195210291010
PRIYS3|ANK37748|DEL37728|KEJRSRC|196004080910|201407061815|195210292110
```

In the above column 5 and column 7 are date columns

User input date format is `DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI`

Desired output:

file.txt

```
OIEX19|BANG37748|DEL37728|WUBXDE|29-10-2000 10:10 AM|201209111625|29-10-1952 12:00 AM
SEETA7|CHA38228|DEL37728|DGSDFE|19-11-2012 07:05 PM|201308071912|29-10-1952 10:10 PM
PRIYS3|ANK37748|DEL37728|KEJRSRC|08-04-1960 09:10 AM|201407061815|29-10-1952 9:10 PM
```

How can I achieve it using `awk`?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What do you mean the date columns are dynamic. Why isn't the 6th column converted. What decides if it is a date or not ?

Comment: Means in the above example 5th and 7th are date columns may be it will be 6th only or 5th only and date formats will differ

Answer (score 0):

With `gawk`:

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{
    gsub(/../, "& ", $5);sub(/ /,"", $5);
    gsub(/../, "& ", $7);sub(/ /,"", $7);
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p", mktime($5" 00")),$6,strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p", mktime($7" 00"))
}' file
```

For sample input output as:

```
OIEX19|BANG37748|DEL37728|WUBXDE|29-10-2000 10:10 AM|201209111625|29-10-1952 12:00 AM
SEETA7|CHA38228|DEL37728|DGSDFE|19-11-2012 07:05 AM|201308071912|29-10-1952 10:10 AM
PRIYS3|ANK37748|DEL37728|KEJRSRC|08-04-1960 09:10 AM|201407061815|29-10-1952 09:10 PM
```

field position as variable to awk:

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" -v dtf="%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p" -v num=5 -v num1=7 '{
    gsub(/../, "& ", $num);sub(/ /,"", $num);
    gsub(/../, "& ", $num1);sub(/ /,"", $num1);
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,strftime(dtf, mktime($num" 00")),$6,strftime(dtf, mktime($num1" 00"))
}' file
```

if all fields that has 12 digits needed to convert:

```
awk -F"|"  -v OFS="|" -v dtf="%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p" '{
    for ( i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if( $i ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && length($i)==12 ) {
            gsub(/../, "& ", $i);
            sub(/ /,"", $i);
            $i=strftime(dtf, mktime($i" 00"))
        }
    }
};
1' file
```

Comment: good thank you but 5th column output is wrong all $5 column has the same answer                                        OIEX19|BANG37748|DEL37728|WUBXDE|01-01-1970 05:29 AM|201209111625|29-10-1952 12:00 AM
SEETA7|CHA38228|DEL37728|DGSDFE|01-01-1970 05:29 AM|201308071912|29-10-1952 10:10 PM
PRIYS3|ANK37748|DEL37728|KEJRSRC|01-01-1970 05:29 AM|201407061815|29-10-1952 9:10 PM

Comment: it works fine for me for the sample input you have provided.

Comment: so what's the issue $5 column has only the problem my os is "redhat linux 6" strftime need any initialization .. i am facing one more issue i assigned date column and date format into variable but date format is not working     dt="%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p"                                             awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{
    gsub(/../, "& ", '$num');sub(/ /,"", '$num');
    gsub(/../, "& ", '$num1');sub(/ /,"", '$num1');
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,strftime('$dt', mktime('$num'" 00")),$6,strftime('$dt', mktime('$num1'" 00"))
}' file.txt

Comment: i edited the answer to accept `num` and `num1` as input variable. I've tested this on RHEL6.

Comment: num and num1 working for me fine but the '$dt' variable i couldnot

Comment: sorry to disturb you i said total column is 7 but it also dynamic it will vary to 9 or 10 or above how can i solve that

Comment: Is the field you want convert always come as last field and second last field? Then use `NF` and `NF-2` to represent those fields.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,no its may be 3rd 4th 5th etc can you show me how to print with out showing $1,$2, $3 etc

Comment: if all fields that has 12 digits needed to convert use my last solution.

Comment: Yes all date columns have 12 digits, but the file also has other than date columns with 12 digit so please convert it to your just before script, num, num1 etc. Your last script convert all the 12 digit columns to corresponding date formats

Answer (score 0):

This **gawk** one-liner will convert your date ($5 and $7) into `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI` format:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|";re="^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)$";rep="\\3-\\2-\\1 \\4:\\5"}
     {$5=gensub(re, rep,"g",$5);$7=gensub(re,rep,"g", $7)}7' file
```

With your data as input, it outputs:

```
OIEX19|BANG37748|DEL37728|WUBXDE|29-10-2000 10:10|201209111625|29-10-1952 00:00
SEETA7|CHA38228|DEL37728|DGSDFE|19-11-2012 07:05|201308071912|29-10-1952 10:10
PRIYS3|ANK37748|DEL37728|KEJRSRC|08-04-1960 09:10|201407061815|29-10-1952 21:10
```

*Note that the 2nd line in your input, I don't know how can you decide `201211190705` as `07:05 PM`. Also `195210291010` as `10:10 PM`. In my codes, I just assume that he input has HH24 format.*

Comment: its working but the date format is user input how can i use this for other date format dt=MON-DD-YYYY HH24:MI

Comment: In my question i said date formats are user input i will change to different date formats

Comment: @joseph ok, I see, then perhaps we could turn to the external date command. pass the user input Format to date. I would check it later if I got time.